# C# - Access property in inheriting class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, collections

I'm trying to access a generic typed property in a child class. In the below example I recreated my problem. Is there a workaround for this problem, or is it simply not possible? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: It's not possible to declare the collection as `A<Model>` or `A<T>`.**

```
public abstract class Model {
    public int Id { get; }
}

public interface I<T> where T: Model {
    ICollection<T> Results { get; }
}

public abstract class A { }

public class A<T> : A, I<T> where T : Model {
    public ICollection<T> Results { get; }
}

public class Example {

    A[] col;

    void AddSomeModels() {
        col = new A[] {
            new A<SomeModel>(),
            new A<SomeOtherModel>()
        }
    }

    void DoSomethingWithCollection() {
        foreach (var a in col) {
            // a.Results is not known at this point
            // is it possible to achieve this functionality?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: They inherit from the same abstract class (lets call it `AbstractModel`). but it's not possible to declare the collection as `A<AbstractModel>`. Allready tried that.

Comment: @GoosvandenBekerom I think I've solved your issue, please see my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do what you intend without some compromises.

First of all, you need to make your interface `I<T>` covariant in `T`:

```
public interface I<out T> where T : Model
{
    IEnumerable<T> Results { get; }
}
```

The first compromise is therefore that `T` can only be an output. `ICollection<T>` isn't covariant in `T` so you'd need to change the type of `Results` to `IEnumerable<T>`.

Once you do this, the following is type safe and therefore allowed:

```
public void DoSomethingWithCollecion()
{
    var genericCol = col.OfType<I<Model>>();

    foreach (var a in genericCol )
    {
        //a.Results is now accessible.
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 That's actually pretty smart. Don't know how the OP will feel about the `IEnumerable<T>` replacement for `ICollection<T>` though.

Comment: The compromise is one I gladly make. This works like a charm, thanks!